# How to measure performance of Angular JS applications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance, performance-testing

I am in process of researching how to measure the performance metrics of an Angular JS applications. I have following questions. Please share your thoughts.

1. Angular JS suits well for one page application. All the interactions happens in one page. In this case, how to calculate page load time?
2. After clicking on Submit, client will request a response from the server. Is there any modern tools capture end-to-end response time. LoadRunner partially supports angular js with ajax truclient protocol. But not 100%.
3. Can we extend the functionalities of Protractor framework to measure the performance of Angular JS applciations?

Comment: Chromes gives you all the tools you need for testing your applications performance

Comment: I want to measure the performance of multiple users, not just one.

Comment: Can't you setup a stopwatch around the 'heavy' code, and asynchronously send the data to server on completion?

Comment: Have you considered the benefit of [f12] for the developer tools for every developer and every functional tester to measure the performance of the code execution inside of the browser?

Comment: Hi James, Sanjay, We need to collect the metrics for more than one users. F12 will give the metrics for one user. Stopwatch is not an option too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If selenium works for your application, you can try using JMeter with the web driver plugin. With a caveat that just like LR's truClient protocol webdriver is resource heavy and greatly limits the number of parallel users you can run on the same hardware.

You can also try a hybrid approach where you create most of the server load just replicating server XHR calls with a regular web script, and doing a smaller percentage of users with web driver where you measure response and js execution time. Obviously this involves more work because you'll be creating twice the number of scripts.